# Entity framework one to one relation

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm having the following models i'm using in my app with Entity Framework 6 code first.

```
public class Customer
{
    public Customer
    {

    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}


public class Address
{
    public Address
    {

    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public int Country { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }              
}
```

When i try to save them I get the following error:

`Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types Customer and Address`

Answer (score 3):

You need to speicify the foreign key relationships.  As mentioned [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/05/01/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-5-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations.aspx), try adding a `[ForeignKey("CustomerId")]` over `public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }` and
`[ForeignKey("AddressId")]` over `public virtual Address Address { get; set; }`, and add those id fields to the model.  Such As:

```
public class Customer
{
    public Customer
    {

    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Addressid { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AddressId")]
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}


public class Address
{
    public Address
    {

    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public int Country { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }              
}
```

Comment: Yep, that solves the problem. Thanks a lot! One more question: I read that can be achieved also using fluent api... and tried to do this: on Customer `HasRequired(c => c.Address).WithRequiredPrincipal(a => a.Customer);` do I have to do the same for Address or this is enough? And it works ...

Comment: It should be defined on the side with the foreign key.  In the example i gave, with both address and customer saving a foreign key, it would need to be on both sides.